Comparing counters and pointers in string loops in C
I write these codes to read characters in a string
The first use Counter:
const char str[] = "Hello World!";

for (unsigned short i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
  char c = str[i];
}

The second use Pointer:
const char str[] = "Hello World!";

for (const char* i = str; *i; i++) {
  char c = *i;
}

So, who is better in performance? And why?

A decent compiler will (almost certainly) generate the same code for both loops.  It's almost certainly not even worth the effort of checking the compiler output except for educational purposes.  Mostly, it'a a question of style.

Unoptimized, it may depend on the implementation, whether it is cheaper to increment (say) 64-bit pointer, or (say) 16-bit integer.

FWIW, the code isn't exactly the same on any optimization level with either gcc or clang. It looks like the compiler still prefers to keep the index variable in the first snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/nb1bb6a4G .. But of course it does not have to be the case and other implementations might behave differently.

"I write these codes"... Program code is uncountable.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

@MikeNakis This is not codes but loops or programs. "Code" is jargon - shortening of "source code". 20 years ago people wrote only "source", now it become "code".

@i486 your opinions are very interesting and I would like to subscribe to your newsletter.

@MikeNakis Read here about source code: https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/definition/source-code

The only useful answer to "which is more performance" is usually to measure it and see. Especially for this kind of micro-optimization, interactions with the rest of your program can easily outweigh any difference measured in isolation.

@i486 you missed Mike's point that it is always "code" (singular/uncountable) in English rather than "codes" (plural).

In general, these two loops are different. The unsigned int loop never terminates if the length of the input string is more than fits in an unsigned int (typically at 65536). Of course in the simple example in the question the compiler can see the input string and "know" it's not long. But also in the question the loop doesn't do anything so the compiler will also just compile it away to nothing.

Based on my understanding of the answers and comments.
the difference depends on the compiler used. If the compiler is good enough, there will usually compile to the same code.
The primary difference would be in memory consumption, when using 16-bit (unsigned short) variable, or 64-bit (const char*) variable (pointer).

There is no universal answer as it depends on multiple factors like the optimization level and the compiler used... But the pointer increment loop seems to be more optimized.
The disassembled code of the Counter version compiled with gcc:
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001149 <+0>: endbr64
   0x000000000000114d <+4>: push   rbp
   0x000000000000114e <+5>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001151 <+8>: sub    rsp,0x20
   0x0000000000001155 <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x000000000000115e <+21>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x0000000000001162 <+25>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000001164 <+27>:    movabs rax,0x6f57206f6c6c6548
   0x000000000000116e <+37>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x15],rax
   0x0000000000001172 <+41>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xd],0x21646c72
   0x0000000000001179 <+48>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x9],0x0
   0x000000000000117d <+52>:    mov    WORD PTR [rbp-0x18],0x0
   0x0000000000001183 <+58>:    jmp    0x119e <main+85>
   0x0000000000001185 <+60>:    movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x0000000000001189 <+64>:    cdqe
   0x000000000000118b <+66>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rbp+rax*1-0x15]
   0x0000000000001190 <+71>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x19],al
   0x0000000000001193 <+74>:    movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x0000000000001197 <+78>:    add    eax,0x1
   0x000000000000119a <+81>:    mov    WORD PTR [rbp-0x18],ax
   0x000000000000119e <+85>:    movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
   0x00000000000011a2 <+89>:    cdqe
   0x00000000000011a4 <+91>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rbp+rax*1-0x15]
   0x00000000000011a9 <+96>:    test   al,al
   0x00000000000011ab <+98>:    jne    0x1185 <main+60>
   0x00000000000011ad <+100>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000000011b2 <+105>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x00000000000011b6 <+109>:   sub    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x00000000000011bf <+118>:   je     0x11c6 <main+125>
   0x00000000000011c1 <+120>:   call   0x1050 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x00000000000011c6 <+125>:   leave
   0x00000000000011c7 <+126>:   ret
End of assembler dump.

Compared to the Pointer version (still gcc):
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000001149 <+0>: endbr64
   0x000000000000114d <+4>: push   rbp
   0x000000000000114e <+5>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000001151 <+8>: sub    rsp,0x30
   0x0000000000001155 <+12>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x000000000000115e <+21>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x0000000000001162 <+25>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x0000000000001164 <+27>:    movabs rax,0x6f57206f6c6c6548
   0x000000000000116e <+37>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x15],rax
   0x0000000000001172 <+41>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xd],0x21646c72
   0x0000000000001179 <+48>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x9],0x0
   0x000000000000117d <+52>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x15]
   0x0000000000001181 <+56>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rax
   0x0000000000001185 <+60>:    jmp    0x1196 <main+77>
   0x0000000000001187 <+62>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x000000000000118b <+66>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
   0x000000000000118e <+69>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x21],al
   0x0000000000001191 <+72>:    add    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],0x1
   0x0000000000001196 <+77>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x000000000000119a <+81>:    movzx  eax,BYTE PTR [rax]
   0x000000000000119d <+84>:    test   al,al
   0x000000000000119f <+86>:    jne    0x1187 <main+62>
   0x00000000000011a1 <+88>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000000011a6 <+93>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x00000000000011aa <+97>:    sub    rdx,QWORD PTR fs:0x28
   0x00000000000011b3 <+106>:   je     0x11ba <main+113>
   0x00000000000011b5 <+108>:   call   0x1050 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x00000000000011ba <+113>:   leave
   0x00000000000011bb <+114>:   ret
End of assembler dump.

You can see that the second code has fewer movzx and no cdqe instructions, meaning less memory accesses, because it directly increments the pointer instead of doing intermediary reads and calculations.
Now with clang the two codes look more similar, but there is still a lot of inefficiency coming from the recalculation of memory offsets (rbp+rax*1-0x11) in the counter version:
Counter with clang:
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401110 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000401111 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000401114 <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000000000040111b <+11>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR ds:0x402004
   0x0000000000401123 <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x11],rax
   0x0000000000401127 <+23>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x40200c
   0x000000000040112e <+30>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x9],eax
   0x0000000000401131 <+33>:    mov    al,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
   0x0000000000401138 <+40>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x5],al
   0x000000000040113b <+43>:    mov    WORD PTR [rbp-0x14],0x0
   0x0000000000401141 <+49>:    movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
   0x0000000000401145 <+53>:    cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp+rax*1-0x11],0x0
   0x000000000040114a <+58>:    je     0x40116c <main+92>
   0x0000000000401150 <+64>:    movzx  eax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
   0x0000000000401154 <+68>:    mov    al,BYTE PTR [rbp+rax*1-0x11]
   0x0000000000401158 <+72>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x15],al
   0x000000000040115b <+75>:    mov    ax,WORD PTR [rbp-0x14]
   0x000000000040115f <+79>:    add    ax,0x1
   0x0000000000401163 <+83>:    mov    WORD PTR [rbp-0x14],ax
   0x0000000000401167 <+87>:    jmp    0x401141 <main+49>
   0x000000000040116c <+92>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000000000040116f <+95>:    pop    rbp
   0x0000000000401170 <+96>:    ret
End of assembler dump.

Pointer with clang:
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000401110 <+0>: push   rbp
   0x0000000000401111 <+1>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000000000401114 <+4>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000000000040111b <+11>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR ds:0x402004
   0x0000000000401123 <+19>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x11],rax
   0x0000000000401127 <+23>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR ds:0x40200c
   0x000000000040112e <+30>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x9],eax
   0x0000000000401131 <+33>:    mov    al,BYTE PTR ds:0x402010
   0x0000000000401138 <+40>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x5],al
   0x000000000040113b <+43>:    lea    rax,[rbp-0x11]
   0x000000000040113f <+47>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rax
   0x0000000000401143 <+51>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x0000000000401147 <+55>:    cmp    BYTE PTR [rax],0x0
   0x000000000040114a <+58>:    je     0x40116a <main+90>
   0x0000000000401150 <+64>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x0000000000401154 <+68>:    mov    al,BYTE PTR [rax]
   0x0000000000401156 <+70>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x21],al
   0x0000000000401159 <+73>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
   0x000000000040115d <+77>:    add    rax,0x1
   0x0000000000401161 <+81>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rax
   0x0000000000401165 <+85>:    jmp    0x401143 <main+51>
   0x000000000040116a <+90>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
   0x000000000040116d <+93>:    pop    rbp
   0x000000000040116e <+94>:    ret
End of assembler dump.

The pointer-based loop is more optimized (Without O2 or O3 optimization) in this case and in most similar cases. But it might be negligible when the loop is short, it is successfully optimized by the compiler, or when working with multi-dimensional data structures.

Directly using the code as pasted by OP is not quite productive, since compilers will happily convert the string into an integer constant (see 6f57206f6c6c6548; decodes to oW olleH) .

OP asks which one of his codes has better performances so I used them as an example, but you are right, it's not a universal example.

Well, both of them optimize away to doing nothing, because c is unused in the end...
